# .NET Entity Framework Core database connection fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple API app using EFC to connect to database. Things work well in my localhost test with

In `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=(local);Database=CentoWebDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {// avoid naming convention;
                var resolver = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
                if (resolver != null)
                    (resolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = null;
            });

        services.AddDbContext<CentoWebDBContext>(
            options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(120)
                )   // set the timeout
        );

        services.AddCors();
    }
```

But when I was trying to make the api app accessible from remote by adding UseKestrel and UseUrls as below, it failed to  connect to the DB.

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://10.10.10.10:5000", "http://localhost:5000")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Error message:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>   Connection id "0HLRC8TEROPG9", Request id "0HLRC8TEROPG9:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>
>   at TSPfizer.CentoMiner.Web.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\shangl02\source\repos\TSolution\CentoMinerWebAPI\Startup.cs:line 43
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)

Seems the connection string is null. don't understand what goes wrong. Did I miss something there?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and see if you are actually getting a connection string value with this line of code -> `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")`

Comment: Actually the connectingStr has content before I add UseKestrel and UseUrls. After adding those two lines in Program->CreateWebHostBuilder, the connectionStr is null.